# Changing image every 5 seconds using external JS file

Tags: image, time, external-js

I am looking for help on how I can edit my code below to show a new image every 5 seconds using HTML and an external JS file. I want it to include 4 images.

I have this code below that include a body on load to change image. How can I move part of the code to an external JS file with it still changing the pictures?

```
        <img id="img1" class="img-responsive">
        <script>
        var imgArray = new Array("img/mockups/about_section/app_about_mockup_1.png","img/mockups/about_section/app_about_mockup_2.png","img/mockups/about_section/app_about_mockup_3.png","img/mockups/about_section/app_about_mockup_4.png");
        var imgCount = 0;
        function startTime() {
          if(imgCount == imgArray.length) {
            imgCount = 0;
          }
          document.getElementById("img1").src = imgArray[imgCount];
          imgCount++;
          setTimeout("startTime()", 5000);
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Use javascript timeOut function to change the src of that img. Of course, javascript need to know the Image url.

Comment: Please provide the JavaScript code that you tried to solve this.

Comment: I just edited it to a javascript one that worked, but want to know how I can call it from external JS. Also if there is a better more optimized way of doing this.